# Populating Android manifest for using parse.com SDK

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am new to Android and trying to incorporate the parse.com sdk. I suspect my android manifest is not correct below around the parse activity. It was working fine in the starter app and I tried to transfer that to my own app. Rest of files should be fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.jorc.fleetmanagement">
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
                <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />


            <application
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                  <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
                    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

                <activity
                    android:name=".MapsActivity"
                    android:label="@string/legal_info"/>
                <activity
                    android:name=".ImageList"
                    android:label="@string/image_info"/>
                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity
                android:name=".StarterApplication"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.parse.APPLICATION_ID"
                    android:value="@string/parse_app_id" />
                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.parse.CLIENT_KEY"
                    android:value="@string/parse_client_key" />
               </activity>


            </application>

    </manifest>
```

The StarterApplication.java is also below.

```
package com.jorc.fleetmanagement;

import android.app.Application;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseACL;
import com.parse.ParseUser;


public class StarterApplication extends Application {

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Enable Local Datastore.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);

    // Add your initialization code here
    Parse.initialize(this,"my id", "my key");

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
    // Optionally enable public read access.
    // defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
  }
}
```

My app build.gradle is also below. Not sure what this mavern and jcenter means as I changed from jcenter to mavern (is this a right thing to do)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
  repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jorc.fleetmanagement"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-tasks:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.11.0'
}
```

The error message is below being fairly sure it is because parse is not connecting and getting any results.

12-05 12:07:33.106 1858-1858/com.jorc.fleetmanagement D/score: Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.io.File com.parse.ParsePlugins.getParseDir()' on a null object reference
12-05 12:07:33.159 1858-1876/com.jorc.fleetmanagement W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
12-05 12:07:33.159 1858-1876/com.jorc.fleetmanagement W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xb4319c20, error=EGL_SUCCESS

Comment: Are you getting an error or something? Please provide some more information about what the problem is.

Comment: Check by providing the id and key directly in the application class.
  Parse.initialize(this,"my id", "my key");
.And also update your error

Comment: just added error message at the end. The ids are fine, stackoverflow has replaced them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referencing the `StarterApplication` in your manifest file.
If you are not referencing it then just make application tag like this

Instead of referencing application class as an activity

```
        <activity
        android:name=".StarterApplication"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Edit your apllication tag like this

```
               <application
                android:name=".StarterApplication" 
                android:allowBackup="true"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:supportsRtl="true"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Just add  `android:name=".StarterApplication"`  to you application tag

Then i think everything should work fine..

Comment: I already have another application tag, I think this will cause error.

Comment: just add android:name=".StarterApplication" to your application tag

Comment: i just updated your application tag its not another tag.